# if conditions break try_files in nginx configuration

Tags: nginx

I have a simple `location` block in my nginx config which matches static files for my website. What I want to do, is to check if the file exists using `try_files`, and if it doesn't, redirect to a URL (in this case specified in the `@cdn` location block). I also want to set some CORS headers.

Below is the relevant configuration.

```
location ~* \.(css|js|jpe?g|png|gif|otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|xml|json)$ {
    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;

        return 204;
    }

    if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, OPTIONS';
    }

    if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, OPTIONS';
    }

    try_files $uri @cdn;
}

location @cdn {
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

The problem is that I get a 404 response if the file does not exist, instead of a 301 redirect. The configuration worked/works fine before adding the CORS headers. If I remove the handling of the headers, everything works as intended, and I get a 301 response back.

Now I have done a bit of reading about why the if directive is bad and should be avoided, but I still don't know why it breaks my configuration. If I understood correctly, it has something to do with either `if` or `add_header` being part of a rewrite module or something like that, and I guess that conflicts with `try_files`. Perhaps I am not accurate here, but either way I am not sure how to fix it.

Why does the presence of `if` and/or `add_header` make nginx give me a 404 instead of a 301 when a file could not be found, and how do I fix it?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://agentzh.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/how-nginx-location-if-works.html might be of interest to you in understanding how `if` works. In your case, when the `if` condition matches, the request is now being served within the `if` context, and `try_files` is not inherited by that context. Or as https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-the-nginx-configuration-file-structure-and-configuration-contexts says "Another thing to keep in mind when using an if context is that it renders a try_files directive in the same context useless."

Also, if the `try_files` falls back to `@cdn` then any headers you've added previously are forgotten, it starts again in the new `location` block, and so the headers need to be added there.

As to how to fix it; you can set variables inside `if`, and `add_header` ignores an empty value, so something like this should work:

```
set $access-control-output 0;
location ~* \.(css|js|jpe?g|png|gif|otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|xml|json)$ {
    set $access-control-output 1;
    try_files $uri @cdn;
}

set $acao = "";
set $acam = "";
if ($access-control-output) {
    set $acao = $http_origin;
    set $acam = "GET, OPTIONS";
}

map "$access-control-output:$request_method" $acma {
    "1:OPTIONS" 1728000; 
    default     "";
}

location @cdn {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $acao;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' $acam;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' $acma;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Edit: You don't care about the headers in the @cdn fallback, in which case you should be able to have something like this:

```
map $request_method $acma {
    "OPTIONS" 1728000; 
    default   "";
}

location ~* \.(css|js|jpe?g|png|gif|otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|xml|json)$ {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' "GET, OPTIONS";
    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' $acma;
    try_files $uri @cdn;
}

location @cdn {
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! That behavior is quite surprising, and I would have had a hard time figuring that out. Actually, setting the headers for the `@cdn` location is not necessary in my particular case. My apologies for not mentioning this in the question - I thought that I did. Could the configuration be simplified further with this in mind? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: No problem, `map` is really useful. I came across the question while trying to solve something similar for someone else, so it was very handy :)